# How to link to product's admin Edit Page from within the admin Order View page?

Tags: magento-1.7

When viewing an order, my employees would like to be able to click on the product's name or SKU, and for that to be a link to that product's Product Info edit page.

I figured out how to change the product name into a link, with that link being the url of the product page on Front End, but I don't want the link going to the front end, I need it to link to the products edit page in Admin Dashboard.

This is the code I used in:

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/**default.phtml**

```
<div class="item-text">
<?php $_pullProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getData('sku')); ?>
<a target="_blank" rel="external" href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl() . $_pullProduct->getData('url_path'); ?>"><?php echo $this->getColumnHtml($_item, 'name') ?></a>
</div>
```

...and this properly links me to the product frontend page. Now, as I said, that's not what I want, so how do I get this to be a link to the product's admin dashboard edit page?

I attempted at changing the above code in the same file to:

```
<div class="item-text">
<?php $_pullProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getData('sku')); ?>
<a target="_blank" rel="external" href="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product/edit', array('id' => $this->getProduct()->getId()))?>"><?php echo $this->getColumnHtml($_item, 'name') ?></a>
</div>
```

...however that's not right, and the Order View page breaks when I try this. I feel like I'm getting close, can any of you help me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div class="item-text">
<?php $_pullProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getData('sku')); ?>
<a target="_blank" rel="external" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product/edit', array('id' => $_pullProduct->getId()))?>"><?php echo $this->getColumnHtml($_item, 'name') ?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks so much. Man, now that I've got this working, I had an employee say he'd like to see this same type of link on the product names within Order Create, in the Search Grid of "Items Ordered". I was hoping I could reuse this same code. I looked in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Search/Grid/Renderer/Product.php , but can't figure out where to add this url code. Any idea how I'd make this happen? I accepted your answer btw! Yay! Thanks again!

Comment: @Marius how to load product in admin means Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', Mage::registry('mymodule')->getData('sku')); is not working

Comment: @KeyurShah. 'not working' it's kind of a large area. Narrow it down a little. Also, ask a different question. There is no point to discuss this in an other question comments.

Comment: after using your method in magento 1.9.1.1 the order page goes blank. is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $_pullProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getData('sku')); ?>
<a target="_blank" rel="external" href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl() . $_pullProduct->getData('url_path'); ?>"><?php echo $this->getColumnHtml($_item, 'name') ?></a>
            <?php $_pullProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getData('sku')); ?>         
<a target="_blank" rel="external" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product/edit', array('id' => $_pullProduct->getId()))?>"><?php echo $this->getColumnHtml($_item, 'qty') ?></a>
```